# ProgrammingError: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "product"

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am using multiple databases in Django and connected default SQLite and PostgreSQL db in the settings.py.

setting.py :

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['routers.db_routers.AppRouter']
DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {'product': 'postgres',}

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    },
    'postgres': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'product',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'password',
        'HOST':'localhost'
    }

}
```

And also made the db_routers.py in the routers folder:

```
class AppRouter:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    product application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read user models go to postgres.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'product':
            return 'postgres'
        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to write user models go to postgres.
        """
        if model._meta.app_label == 'product':
            return 'postgres'
        return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """
        Allow relations if a model in the user app is involved.
        """
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'product' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'product':
           return True
        elif 'product' not in [obj1._meta.app_label, obj2._meta.app_label]:
            return True

        return None


    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        """
        Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'product_db'
        database.
        """
        if app_label == 'product':
            return db == 'postgres'
        return None
```

here, it's model.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'product'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have successfully made the tables by running `python3 manage.py makemigrations` but when I try to migrate using `python3 manage.py migrate --database=postgres`, I am getting this error:  `ProgrammingError: relation "product" does not exist. SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "product"`And the table is also not present in PgAdmin.

migration.py of product:

```
# Generated by Django 3.2.5 on 2021-07-16 13:25

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Product',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=100)),
                ('price', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)),
                ('weight', models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)),
                ('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('updated_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'product',
                'managed': False,
            },
        ),
    ]
```

Error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/

Django Version: 3.2.5
Python Version: 3.8.10
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework.authtoken',
 'post',
 'product']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (relation "product" does not exist
LINE 1: ...product"."created_at", "product"."updated_at" FROM "product"
                                                              ^
) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 239, in get
    return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 46, in list
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 745, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 246, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 663, in to_representation
    return [
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 280, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/rudrakshi/Desktop/Rose/assignment/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /api/product/
Exception Value: relation "product" does not exist
LINE 1: ...product"."created_at", "product"."updated_at" FROM "product"
                                                              ^
```

After running makemigrations and then migrate,
I run my server and when I hit the endpoint- 'api/product/' I got this error - relation "product" does not exist LINE 1: ...product"."created_at", "product"."updated_at" FROM "product"

[image]

Comment: Can you share the relevant migration file that Django created?

Comment: What if you use `--database postgres`?

Comment: Please show the _full_ stack trace of the error.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Now I have added the migrations.py file.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I have added the pic of my error.

Comment: @Rudrakshi not that picture... See that "Switch to copy-and-paste view"? Click that, copy the error and add it to your question (That interactive mode is not very useful unless you can actually access it).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Now I have added the error. Is that fine?

Comment: I though you said you got the error while running `python3 manage.py migrate --database=postgres`? The traceback instead shows that the error occurs on a _request_. Other than that why does your migration file has `'managed': False,` when it is not so in your model?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Actually, I found this in one of the StackOverflow posts so I added it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234975/discussion-between-rudrakshi-and-abdul-aziz-barkat).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your migration file you have `'managed': False,`, what does this mean? It means that you don't want the migration system to manage this model. This means that running `migrate` will not cause the corresponding tables to be created in the database.  **Don't** edit migration files unless you understand what you are doing!

Remove whatever changes you might have made to the migration file, especially that `'managed': False,` and then run:

```
python manage.py migrate product zero --fake
```

This will cause Django to mark all migrations for the app "product" as unapplied. This is fine since it seems like this is your initial migration, otherwise you might have wanted to change `zero` to some migration name. Next run:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: getting this error now - relation "product" does not exist
LINE 1: ...product"."created_at", "product"."updated_at" FROM "product"

Comment: @Rudrakshi when do you get this error exactly? When you run `migrate`? Please show it in your question (the _full_ stack trace).

Comment: I have added my error. Please let me know if you want any other details. I have removed the `managed: False` and then run makemigrations and migrate again.